# How to use a negated every(), or just some(), in Javascript to check that a key is missing from every iteration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, methods, negation

Having trouble wrapping my mind around negating an `every()` statement in js. Can someone help me out?

### Here's the data/response I need to work with:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "categoryName": "category1",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "product1",
                    "targetKey": {
                        "bananas": "are good"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "product2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "category2",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "product3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "product4",
                    "targetKey": {
                        "bananas": "are good"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to execute code ONLY WHEN NO !targetKey is found (at all, anywhere), and I only want to execute it ONCE, not per iteration. If even one `targetKey` is present in the response, this cannot return.

The above response would look like this, if the case was true:

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "categoryName": "category1",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "product1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "product2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "categoryName": "category2",
            "products": [
                {
                    "name": "product3"
                },
                {
                    "name": "product4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### What I tried:

- Code loops and I don't want it to throw 300 times, so `find()` is not an option. Not confident that breaking loop allows it to properly iterate.
- `every()` seems like the right fit for these preconditions, but I don't know how to negate it.
- `some()` might work, since it stops checking after it finds one `targetKey`, but it refused to work for me at all. Could have been programming error.
- `indexOf()`, but it was always returning -1, even when the response returned. Again, could have been improperly programmed.

### Here's what I want to know:

#### 1. How (or, where?) do I properly negate `every()`, so that the language makes the right checks?

Even if it's the wrong method to use, can it be done and what is the proper place for the negation? Are either of these correct? Both seem equally happy, but I'm guessing one or both are completely wrong.

```
for (const category of response.categories) {
    if (Object.keys(category.products).every(product => !product.targetKey)) {
        throw new Error("targetKey is missing!");
    };
}
```

```
for (const category of response.categories) {
    if (!Object.keys(category.products).every(product => product.targetKey)) {
        throw new Error("targetKey is missing!");
    };
}
```

##### 2. I'm guessing these don't mean the same thing. Can you explain the difference?

#### 3. If I do need to use `if some()` + `else{}` what does that code look like?

Sorry for the long post and many thanks.

Comment: Your first approach is fine but what you want might not be `Object.keys` but `Object.values`. Since `Object.keys` only gives you an array of strings and `string.targetKey` is always going to be `undefined`.

Comment: @HaoWu Won't `Object.values` require me to look by the value of `targetKey`? The values can vary, but the key name is always going to be 'targetKey'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nesting [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and negating the result will tell you when the property is not present.

```js
const withTargetKey = {"categories":[{"categoryName":"category1","products":[{"name":"product1","targetKey":{"bananas":"are good"}},{"name":"product2"}]},{"categoryName":"category2","products":[{"name":"product3"},{"name":"product4","targetKey":{"bananas":"are good"}}]}]};
const withoutTargetKey = {"categories":[{"categoryName":"category1","products":[{"name":"product1"},{"name":"product2"}]},{"categoryName":"category2","products":[{"name":"product3"},{"name":"product4"}]}]};

const detectProp = ({ categories }, prop = "targetKey") =>
  categories.some(({ products }) =>
    products.some((product) => Object.hasOwn(product, prop))
  );

if (!detectProp(withTargetKey)) {
  console.log("withTargetKey does not have any targetKeys"); // won't see this
}

if (!detectProp(withoutTargetKey)) {
  console.log("withoutTargetKey does not have any targetKeys");
}
```

See also [Object.hasOwn()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn)

Comment: Apologies but copied your code skeleton for my answer.

Comment: @Rajesh not a problem. I like your approach though you probably don't need a regex

Comment: Thanks for the solution with `some()`. Looks like I was close with my some() code, but I didn't think to use `hasOwn()` there and I had it in the loop still because I didn't know how else to iterate through categories and products. I've learned at least 3 new things from this answer. This, with a minor tweak to use `responseBody` in place of `withoutTargetKey` seems to be working really well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to check if anyone object has key, you can do a string search.

#### Logic:

- Create a regex to test string. Pattern would be `"<key>":`
- Then use `JSON.stringify` and test if this object has this key in any specific level

The benefit of this approach is that you can do it for deeply nested objects without knowing/ navigating to a specific path. Con is that if you have a specific path, this will need tweeking and beats the purpose of not looping

```js
const withTargetKey = {"categories":[{"categoryName":"category1","products":[{"name":"product1","targetKey":{"bananas":"are good"}},{"name":"product2"}]},{"categoryName":"category2","products":[{"name":"product3"},{"name":"product4","targetKey":{"bananas":"are good"}}]}]};
const withoutTargetKey = {"categories":[{"categoryName":"category1","products":[{"name":"product1"},{"name":"product2"}]},{"categoryName":"category2","products":[{"name":"product3"},{"name":"product4"}]}]};

const detectProp = ({ categories }, prop = "targetKey") => {
  return new RegExp(`"${prop}":`, ['gi']).test(JSON.stringify(categories))
}

console.log('WithTargetKey: ', detectProp(withTargetKey))

console.log('WithoutTargetKey: ', detectProp(withoutTargetKey))
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach is very straightforward when you can phrase your goal.

> We need to know if in every category and in every product the `targetKey` is **not** (here you negate) included.

Note that negating `product.targetKey` can produce the wrong output when its value is falsy (null, undefined, 0). So it is not a safe way to check for existing keys.

This is another approach to @Phil's that considers using `Object.keys` combined with `Array.prototype.includes` instead of `Object.hasOwn` and nested `every` instead of `some`.

```js
const responseRegular ={categories:[{categoryName:"category1",products:[{name:"product1"},{name:"product2"}]},{categoryName:"category2",products:[{name:"product3"},{name:"product4"}]}]};
const responseTarget={categories:[{categoryName:"category1",products:[{name:"product1",targetKey:{bananas:"are good"}},{name:"product2"}]},{categoryName:"category2",products:[{name:"product3"},{name:"product4",targetKey:{bananas:"are good"}}]}]};

const isValid = (responseType) =>
  responseType.categories.every(category => 
    category.products.every(product => !Object.keys(product).includes("targetKey")))

console.log(isValid(responseRegular), isValid(responseTarget))
```